# how to merge files in TFS using scripts

Tags: powershell, tfs

I need to merge files from Dev branch to ReleaseCandidate branch. Using the GUI to do this for 120 files is not a good way to spend time so I'm hoping I can either run a PowerShell or batch file script (using TF) to do this...

They are unfortunately not in one changeset so I've seen on here and on Google how to do this for specific changesets. I have a list of files and I need to have an easy way to do this for the list of files in TFS.

1. TFS 2010
2. Visual Studio 2010

$/DBA/Dev/siu_prod/Schema Objects/Schemas/dbo/Programmability/Stored Procedures/abc.sql
$/DBA/Dev/siu_prod/Schema Objects/Schemas/dbo/Programmability/Stored Procedures/def.sql

etc... needs to be merged to

$/DBA/ReleaseCandidate/siu_prod/Schema Objects/Schemas/dbo/Programmability/Stored Procedures/abc.sql
$/DBA/ReleaseCandidate/siu_prod/Schema Objects/Schemas/dbo/Programmability/Stored Procedures/def.sql

Can you help me? Thanks!

Comment: Why are you merging individual files? That's a really bad idea -- you should be merging entire branches at a time, not individual files or changesets.

Comment: Yeah, you're right, but I'm stuck in a legacy process that I have to follow. Do you have any ideas?